# How to use Update Statement in SQL Server with join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The code below works fine with MS Access but I cannot make it work with SQL Server 2008.

```
UPDATE Borrow INNER JOIN BorrowDetails 
ON Borrow.BorrowID = BorrowDetails.BorrowID 
SET BorrowDetails.Returned = True 
WHERE BookID = 1 AND MemberID = 1
```

Any idea please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE BorrowDetails
SET BorrowDetails.Returned = True 
FROM BorrowDetails
INNER JOIN Borrow ON Borrow.BorrowID = BorrowDetails.BorrowID 
WHERE BookID = 1 AND MemberID = 1
```

Comment: How to optimize above query if second table i.e. Borrow has millions of records while first table i.e. BorrowDetails has few thousand records?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: I dont have a definite answer to it. Does using an `EXISTS` clause help? I might suggest asking a fresh question with schema details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE bd
SET bd.Returned = 1
FROM BorrowDetails bd
INNER JOIN Borrow b ON bd.BorrowID = b.BorrowID    
WHERE b.BookID = 1 AND b.MemberID = 1
```

Comment: this is the error I got after pasting in the sql management studio tools `Column or expression 'Returned' cannot be updated.
This SQL statement type cannot be used in a view or function.
Only a SELECT statement can be used.`

Comment: @jaypabs Sorry you can't update columns from different tables, you should update columns from one table for example `BorrowDetails` this why you had this error since you did FROM borrow and `SET bd.Returned`. You have to reference the `FROM BorrowDetails bd` instead like in my edit.

Comment: Although I would set the value to 1 rather than true.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE x
SET x.Returned = True 
FROM (
      SELECT Returned 
      FROM Borrow INNER JOIN BorrowDetails ON Borrow.BorrowID = BorrowDetails.BorrowID 
      WHERE BookID = 1 AND MemberID = 1
      ) x
```